# Lowercase filenames

Tags: assets, config, filesystem

I've been unable to find a config option for giving all uploaded files and their transforms lowercase filenames.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively.  You can make a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com) and/or write a simple plugin that listens for the [`assets.onBeforeUploadAsset`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#assets-onBeforeUploadAsset) event, then calls [strtolower](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) on the filename.